# Iterating through a python list of dictonaries, that may contain further lists of dictionaries etc

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I always seem to get stuck on this, so wondering if you can help.  I have a list of dictionaries that contain other lists and further dictionaries, I never know how many. If I want to search for a specific value how do I do that? for example,

```
[{'department_id': 'DEP1', 'students': [{'username': 'tim', 'email_address': 'tim@college.com'}]}, 
 {'department_id': 'DEP2', 'students': [{'username': 'steve', 'email_address': 'steve@college.com'}]}, 
 {'department_id': 'DEP3', 'students': [{'username': 'John', 'email_address': 'john@college.com'}, {'username': 'Helen'}]}]
```

taking this datastructure, I want to search for email address of steve@college.com and return that he belongs in DEP2.

when the structure is fixed, there are many examples, but I am struggling with dictionaries in lists which could be in further lists of dictionaries, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_department(data, email):
    for sub in data:
        if sub['students'][0]['email_address'] == email:
            return sub['department_id']

>>> find_department(data, 'steve@college.com')
'DEP2'
```